# What is the correct sentence / sentences from following four sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

What is the correct sentence / sentences from following four sentences?

1. How to Create Custom Post Types in WordPress Programmatically?
2. How to Create Custom Post Types in WordPress in Programmatically?
3. How to Create WordPress Custom Post Types Programmatically?
4. How to Create WordPress Custom Post Types in Programmatically?

And can I know that the word "Programmatically" is wrong? I asked it because when I typing it is underlined in red...

Comment: Only #1 looks correct to me. And yes, programmatically is a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both #1 and #3 are close, with #1 being the better of the two - but you're missing a [subject](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/subject-and-object). You have an object - "Custom Post Types" - but nothing to act upon it.

Assuming you are the subject:

> How **do I** create custom post types in WordPress programmatically?

Also, your question reads more naturally if you shift the [adverb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/where-is-the-correct-place-to-place-adverbs-in-sentences) (programmatically) in front of the verb:

> How do I programmatically create custom post types in WordPress?

Comment: Thanks vocoder. This is used in a title of a blog post. That's why I did not use the subject.

Comment: Oh right, then remove the question mark, and #1 works. :)

Comment: Thanks, And do you have any idea that why "Programmatically" consider as misspelling word in text editors?

Comment: It seems to be a quirk of whatever dictionary your browser/editor uses. Microsoft Word and Edge (Internet Explorer) recognise it as a valid word, Google Chrome and OpenOffice don't for whatever reason.